# incomparable types: int and Number in java 8

Tags: compilation, java-8, java

Suppose I have the following code:

```
class proba {
    boolean fun(Number n) {
        return n == null || 0 == n;
    }
}
```

This compiles without problem using openjdk 7 (debian wheezy), but fails to compile when using openjdk 8, with the following error (even when using -source 7):

```
proba.java:3: error: incomparable types: int and Number
    return n == null || 0 == n;
                          ^
1 error
```

How to go around this:

- Is there a compiler option for this construct to continue working in java 8?
- Should I make lots of consecutive ifs with instanceof checks of all of Number's subclasses and casting and then comparing one-by one? This seems ugly...
- Other suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is actually a bugfix (see [JDK-8013357](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8013357)): the Java-7 behavior contradicted the [JLS §15.21](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21):

> The equality operators may be used to compare two operands that are convertible (§5.1.8) to numeric type, or two operands of type `boolean` or `Boolean`, or two operands that are each of either reference type or the `null` type. All other cases result in a compile-time error.

In your case one operand is numeric type, while other is reference type (`Number` is not convertible to the numeric type), so it should be a compile-time error, according to the specification.

This change is mentioned in [Compatibility Guide for Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html) (search for "primitive").

Note that while your code compiles in Java-7 it works somewhat strangely:

```
System.out.println(new proba().fun(0)); // compiles, prints true
System.out.println(new proba().fun(0.0)); // compiles, prints false
System.out.println(new proba().fun(new Integer(0))); // compiles, prints false
```

That's why Java-7 promotes 0 to `Integer` object (via autoboxing), then compares two objects by reference which is unlikely what you want.

To fix your code, you may convert `Number` to some predefined primitive type like `double`:

```
boolean fun(Number n) {
    return n == null || 0 == n.doubleValue();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, n.intValue() is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare Number and int - call Number.intValue() and then compare.